# ERROR:root:compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting mingw32-make: *** [obj/pgText.o] Error 1 mingw32-make: write error

Tags: makefile, cmake, emscripten

I got continuously this error anyone has the solution for this.

```
ERROR:root:compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
mingw32-make: *** [obj/pgText.o] Error 1
mingw32-make: write error
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

System Details:
image
```

Comment: Do you have enough space on your harddisk?

Comment: how much space it needs ? because i have same error. following this tutorial : http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html